# How to stop illustrator from making my stroke bigger when duplicating file or Exporting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a file I've been working on and I placed in a link file of an Icon I previously made, and in the original illustrator file it looks fine, but when I save the artboard to a separate file or when I duplicate the same file the stroke on the Icon becomes thicker.

Original

[image: Original]

Duplicate File

[image: Duplicate file]

Comment: Im on a mac and when I use quick look or preview it comes out normal but whenever I open it in illustrator it gets messed up, even the original one now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to a size difference between the documents/artboards. Since strokes are given a set value (5px for example) their size can vary greatly, depending on the overal size of the document.  A 5 pixel stroke on an object that's 2000px wide will seem much smaller than on one that's 100px wide.

I suggest you expand the appearance of anything that has a stroke.

Select anything you've applied a stroke to and go to **Object > Expand...**

[image]

The object on the left has been expanded, you can see that the stroke is now a physical path, instead of just a style, as on the right.

[image]

Layers:

[image]

Comment: I tried this and I replaced the linked file and it works fine as it always did, but the problem still happens when I duplicate the file or when I save an artboard by itself

Comment: Never mind this worked when I expanded the original file and instead of relinking I had to place it again, thank you!